# When talking about the weather, there doesn't seem to be any way of saying "Warm"

Tags: word-usage

Am I missing something?  Is there no other **commonly** used word for elevated temperatures when speaking about the weather other than "caldo"?  All I see is this word used with some sort of modifier...  What about warm?  What about sizzling?  Am I missing something?  The only other word I have encountered is **afoso**.   The same kind of thing seems to happening on the other side of the temperature scale with "freddo".  Just cold?  Not chilly, or freezing or mild, etc. to imply a degree of hot or coldness?

Perhaps, it is just my (very) limited exposure to the language, so far?

I am not looking for a list of synonyms, I am looking for information about commonly used words actually used in expressions, as you would encounter if you were inside and asking someone who just came in if you needed a sweater or a heavy coat, or if it was so hot that you needed to dress in shorts and a sleeveless top. In English, we would say, "It is **warm** but not really hot."  Or, "It is very **mild** outside, you do not need a sweater."

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, it is just your limited exposure to the language. May I suggest that rather than suggesting that “there doesn't seem to be” any such and such word in a language you don't master, you just ask for a word with the meaning you are interested in?

Comment: As DaG said its just limited vocabulary. For example we can express the English "sizzling" as solleone, calura, canicola ecc... and more if we dont limit it to the weather

Comment: @DaG  Well, I understand your point, but 1) I am terrified of running afoul of the rules, here, and do not want to be perceived as using the site as a dictionary. and 2) although I have looked it up, I am also interested in not sounding very strange when I speak.  So, on both counts, I thought I would ask here.  May I quote from the answer below?  This answered my question nicely. "There are words for warm / mild, but they aren't commonly used in the normal speech."  If you are starting from scratch, as I am, I think it is important to know these things as well as the grammar and vocabulary...

Comment: Of course it is important, and of course you are welcome to ask any clarification about Italian. I just don't understand why you assumed that there doesn't seem to be any word etc.

Comment: Oh dear.  Well,like most of my explanations, this one involves a journey.  I followed a link included in a question posted here that was temporarily put on hold-to wit; the one asking about good sources for phonetic spellings of Italian.  The link was to Lang-8,  a place where you can get writing proofread.  After correcting several many essays from the far east involving their new year, I posted a short essay, that encapsulated my question.  No one there has yet ventured any more suggestions, for "warm".  Admittedly, it is a very small sample, but, that where I got this impression.

Comment: well you know how assuming goes ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are words for warm / mild, but they aren't commonly used in the normal speech.

One can say "*temperato*" (more referred to a regional climate than a specific day), "*piacevole*" (literally "*pleasant*", which indicates a just-right warmth), "*tiepido*" (literally "*mild*", also used in its variation "*tiepidino*").

Curiously enough, there is a widely used term for "*chilly*", which is "*fresco*" (often used in the spoken language in its variation "*freschino*" -> "*fa freschino oggi!*")

You can translate the usages in a non literal way: something like "*It is warm but not really hot*" would possibly become "*Fa caldo, ma non da morire/ci/ne*".

"*It is very mild outside, you do not need a sweater*" could become either "*Non ti serve il maglione, non fa [così] freddo*" or "*Non ti serve il maglione, si sta bene [anche senza]*".

Comment: - It took me awhile, but "Fa caldo, ma non da morirete" would mean - It's hot, but not enough to kill you?  ;-)  I like it.

Comment: @Msfolly Yes, although it is *morire*, not *morirete* (which is the wrong tense). I'd personally use *si sta bene* (roughly, *we're fine*).

Comment: @Msfolly my compact form "morire/ci/ne" means that you can find usages of "morire", "morirci" and "morirne"

Answer (score 3):

We say "mite", which is like "mild" in English. Like you said, it's not very common but "oggi il tempo è mite" will do. A more common but less literal translation is "Si sta bene", it feels good. Ciao.